# PHP array merge

Tags: php, array-merge

I have two arrays as follows:

Array I:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [did] => 1
            [dname] => AJAy
            [dsp] => 3
            [dqu] => abc
            [isactive] => Y
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [did] => 2
            [dname] => Vijay
            [dsp] => 4
            [dqu] => abc
            [isactive] => Y
        )
)
```

Array II:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recno] => 1
            [dname] => AJAy
            [dsp] =>
            [did]=>
            [dqu] => 
            [isactive] => Y
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [recno] => 2
            [dname] => Vijay
            [dsp] =>
            [did]=>
            [dqu] => 
            [isactive] => Y
        )
)
```

I want to update values of did, dsp, dqu from array I to array II based on match value of dname , I tried with array merge its not work out for my situation, please help me

Comment: @Paul I guess he will need to write a function, since not only it will be recursive, but it also must have a condition.

Comment: Yes, array_merge_recursive doesn't work, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$arr1 = Array(
    Array(
        'did'       => 1,
        'dname'     => 'AJAy',
        'dsp'       => 3,
        'dqu'       => 'abc',
        'isactive'  => 'Y',
    ),
    Array(
        'did'       => 2,
        'dname'     => 'Vijay',
        'dsp'       => 4,
        'dqu'       => 'abc',
        'isactive'  => 'Y',
    ),
);
$arr2 = Array(
    Array(
        'recno'     => 2,
        'dname'     => 'Vijay',
        'dsp'       => '',
        'did'       => '',
        'dqu'       => '',
        'isactive'  => 'Y',
    ),
    Array(
        'recno'     => 1,
        'dname'     => 'AJAy',
        'dsp'       => '',
        'did'       => '',
        'dqu'       => '',
        'isactive'  => 'Y',
    ),
);

for($i1=0; $i1<count($arr1); $i1++) {
    for ($i2=0; $i2<count($arr2); $i2++) {
        if ($arr1[$i1]['dname'] == $arr2[$i2]['dname']) {
            $arr2[$i2]['did'] = $arr1[$i1]['did'];
            $arr2[$i2]['dsp'] = $arr1[$i1]['dsp'];
            $arr2[$i2]['dqu'] = $arr1[$i1]['dqu'];
        }
    }
}
print_r($arr2);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recno] => 2
            [dname] => Vijay
            [dsp] => 4
            [did] => 2
            [dqu] => abc
            [isactive] => Y
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [recno] => 1
            [dname] => AJAy
            [dsp] => 3
            [did] => 1
            [dqu] => abc
            [isactive] => Y
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<?php
$a = array
(
        0 => array
        (
                1 => 'bat'
        ),
        1 => array
        (
                10 => 'hamar'
        )
);
$b = array
(
        0 => array
        (
                2 => 'bi'
        ),
        1 => array
        (
                11 => 'hamaike'
        )
);

$length = count($a);
$tmp = array();
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
{
        $tmp[$i] = array_merge($a[$i], $b[$i]);
}

print_r($tmp);
?>
```

edit: it's better array_merge_recursive from comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Dude you can try with array_combine()  ...
it will Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values..

but you have to give condition.for matching values..